# Paypal Button on AMP-HTML page

Tags: paypal, amp-html

Is there a way of including a PayPal "Buy Button" in an AMP-HTML page?
The PayPal button requires external script, so the page won't validate. Is there a workaround?

Thanks

Ales

Comment: Hope you have gone through [Payments In Amp](https://ampbyexample.com/advanced/payments_in_amp/).

Answer (score 0):

PayPal has a series of [HTML button examples](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/html_example_buy_now/#) which don't need a script that you can use. As they rely on forms you may need to also pair it with the `amp-form` [component to get them to pass validation](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-form).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use  the html buttons of paypal don't work while the "pay now" button image cannot display

You need to add this code in header:

body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}

Also you need to import amp-iframe script

You can see here the details about this problem:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/367201/amp-and-paypal-form-cors-issue?newreg=fc62243f85a2428fb9e0d2f4e6d03233

You can see here my code example: https://www.dropbox.com/s/q0qlsab4934es3z/paypal.html?dl=0